# In KnockoutJS, how can I dynamically disable or enable a button based on an observed value?

Tags: knockout.js

I'd like to disable a button in a form until a checkbox is checked. I was looking at the Knockout `attr` binding, but it only controls the value of an attribute on an element, not whether or not that attribute should be attached to an element.

Here's what I tried that doesn't seem to work:

```
<a href=#" data-bind="attr: $root.isChecked() ? {} : { 'disabled' : 'disabled' }">Save Changes</a>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would want to bind your checkbox using the `checked` binding against a boolean on your view model, then you would use either the `enable` or `disable` binding on your button.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/enable-binding.html

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/M6BzW/